# Exporting Access Tables to Excel Error

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel, identifier

I am trying to export my access tables to excel but keep getting the "Error, Expected Identifier" when I input my query and path name. Below is the code:

```
Sub exportToXl()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim dbTable As String

Sub dmwExport("SuperDash_Usage_Rpt", "L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx")

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _

TransferType:=acExport, _

SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _

TableName:="SuperDash_Usage_Rpt", _

FileName:=L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx, _

HasFieldNames:=True

End Sub
```

This is the exact queryname from my access table and the path that I want to exported table to go to. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Sub dmwExport` to `Call dmwExport`

Comment: I am getting the error where I define the query name after the Sub dmwexport("Superdash_Usage_rpt", "L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx")

Comment: @JennaTerral Updated answer

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `" "` around your file path in order for it to read it as text rather than a variable.

Like so:

```
Sub exportToXl()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim dbTable As String

Sub dmwExport("SuperDash_Usage_Rpt", "L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx")

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _

TransferType:=acExport, _

SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _

TableName:="SuperDash_Usage_Rpt", _

'Added "" around file path in order to be read as text
FileName:="L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx", _

HasFieldNames:=True

End Sub
```

You may also be able to "short-hand" the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet`.

Example:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SuperDash_Usage_Rpt", "L:\WF Reporting\Superdash\SuperdashRpt.xlsx", True
```

I hope this helps!